# Simple date format in IST and KST

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I use the following simple date format to parse a string,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
String time = "Wed Mar 06 21:00:00 IST 2014";
Date date = dateFormat.parse(time);
```

This throws no error whreas,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
String time = "Wed Mar 06 21:00:00 KST 2014";
Date date = dateFormat.parse(time);
```

Throws unparseable date exception.

where,
**IST - Indian standard time**
**KST - korean standard time**

I have decided to remove time zone because of the exception.

Is there any other way to work around this issue?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the dates are invalid, hence both would throw the error:

```
String time = "Wed Mar Thu 21:00:00 IST 2014";
```

**Thu** is invalid as the day of the week is already consumed by `EEE - Wed` combination. You need to set a day of the month there.

Try parsing the following date, it should work for your case:

```
String time = "Wed Mar 12 21:00:00 KST 2014";
```

Comment: @user3164187 what happens if you use `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);`, meaning try changing the Locale to US and run (though it doesn't align with accepting IST and not KST)

Answer (score 4):

## Avoid Time Zone Codes

Avoid those 3 or 4 letter codes for time zones. They are neither standardized nor unique. For example, the `IST` you cite as "Indian Standard Time" is *also* "Irish Standard Time". Plus they are confusing when in fact you may mean "Summer Time"/"Daylight Saving Time". Instead use [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), usually made up of a country plus primary city.

## Use Sensible Formats For Date-Time Strings

That format "Wed Mar Thu 21:00:00 IST 2014" is not good. Besides being wrong (looks like you typed "Wed" or "Thu" where you should have a day-of-month number), it uses the 3-4 letter code, contains superfluous data (day of week), and assumes English readers. When moving date-time values around as text, use the sensible [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sssZ` such as `2014-03-04T23:20:28Z`.

If changing that format is out of your control, you'll have to determine all the possible 3-4 letter codes that may be used in your data sets and see if your date-time library can handle them.

## Avoid java.util.Date/Calendar

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. They are outmoded as of Java 8 with the new java.time package. That package is based on the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Use either Joda-Time or java.time.

## Joda-Time

Note that in contrast to java.util.Date, a Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object truly knows its assigned time zone.

Here's some Joda-Time 2.3 example code.

```
String inputIso = "2014-03-19T21:00:00+05:30";
DateTimeZone timeZoneIndia = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = new DateTime( inputIso, timeZoneIndia );

// Adjust to Korea Time.
DateTimeZone timeZoneKorea = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Seoul" );
DateTime dateTimeKorea = dateTimeIndia.withZone( timeZoneKorea );

// Adjust to UTC (GMT).
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeKorea.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );

String inputLame = "Thu Mar 20 21:00:00 KST 2014";
DateTimeZone timeZone = null;
if( inputLame.contains( "IST" )) { // Assume IST = India time.
    timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(  "Asia/India" );
    inputLame = inputLame.replace( " IST ", " ");
}
if( inputLame.contains( "KST" )) { // Assume KST = Korea time.
    timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(  "Asia/Seoul" );
    inputLame = inputLame.replace( " KST ", " ");
}
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" ).withZone( timeZone ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.ENGLISH );
DateTime dateTimeLame = formatter.parseDateTime( inputLame );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndia: " + dateTimeIndia );
System.out.println( "dateTimeKorea: " + dateTimeKorea );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeLame: " + dateTimeLame );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeIndia: 2014-03-19T21:00:00.000+05:30
dateTimeKorea: 2014-03-20T00:30:00.000+09:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-03-19T15:30:00.000Z
dateTimeLame: 2014-03-20T21:00:00.000+09:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code and see if KST is a valid time zone id

```
    String[] timezoneIdArr = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    for (String tzId : timezoneIdArr) {
        System.out.println(tzId);
    }
```

If not, then enter zone id like "Asia/Seoul" or something. That should work.

Please note that I have not tried it. Please check exact spellings of the time zones.

Update:

Try the code below. See what KST yields. Uncomment and try with Asia/Seoul. For your reference, uncomment and see how PST works.

```
private static void calTest() {
    String zone = "KST";
    //String zone = "Asia/Seoul";
    //String zone = "PST";

    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //get calendar of Korea time zone.
    Calendar kst = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone));

    //set its time to a UTC millisecond value. probably redundant, but just to demonstrate
    kst.setTimeInMillis(millis);

    String formattedKst = formatTime(kst);
    System.out.println(" Original - " + formattedKst);

    //now we convert the formatted string back to a Calendar . 
    Calendar parsedKst = parseTime(formattedKst, zone);
    System.out.println(" Parsed - ");
    System.out.println("" + parsedKst.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"
             + (parsedKst.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
             + parsedKst.get(Calendar.DATE) + " "
             + parsedKst.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
             + parsedKst.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
             + parsedKst.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "."
             + parsedKst.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + " "
             + parsedKst.getTimeZone().getID() + " "
             + parsedKst.getTimeZone().getDisplayName() + " "
            );




}

private static Calendar parseTime(String formattedDateTime, String ID) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX zzz");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ID));
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try {
        sdf.parse(formattedDateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sdf.getCalendar();
}

private static String formatTime(Calendar cal) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX zzz");
    sdf.setCalendar(cal);
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```